# Slow PHP searching in database

Tags: php, sql, pdo

So I have a database of 20mil+ rows, and I need a search function.
So I have a PDO code to search, and when the searched username is in the database it it not very fast but fine, about 0.9 seconds. But when the searched username is not in the database it takes more then 10 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
$p = $_GET["p"];
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=x", "x", "x");
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id` from `dbsearch` WHERE `username` = :p LIMIT 1");
  $sth->bindParam(':p', $p);

  $sth->execute();
  $result = $sth->fetchAll();

  if($result)
  {
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
      echo $row["id"];
    }
  }
  else {
    echo "none";
  }
```

I searched for this on stackoverflow and I could only find things like sphinx, which is not possible for me since I am on a shared hosting (namecheap)

Anyone that can help me? thx.

Comment: Do you have an index for the username column?

Comment: @kylek I am not very good in sql or things in that way, I dont think I have a index. How do I add that and does it only need to be on the searched column (username) or on all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just need an index:

```
create index idx_dbsearch_username_id on dbsearch(username, id)
```

The reason it goes slower when the name is not in the table is because the database has to search the entire table to be sure it is not there.  If the name is in the table, then it can stop at the first occurrence.  With an index, both should be very, very fast.

Comment: What is the reason for including the id column in the index?

Comment: Right, that was it! It is now indeed very fast in both ways. Also I am wondering the same thing as kyle k, what column you need to index and why?

Comment: @kylek . . . So the index will cover the query.  This means that MySQL doesn't need to reference the data pages -- all the information is in the index.  In some databases, the primary key is not needed for an index (or for a clustered index), but I prefer to be explicit even in that case.