# Extracting matching words to JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, json

Is it possible to extract those that match those in the JSON file as separate JSON data?

```
<?php

$searchArray = array('settings all','print', 'sum', 'industry'); // total 50K words


function sanitize($string,$searchArray) {
    $repl = array_map("dashReplace", $searchArray);
    $pattern = array_map("insertWordBoundaries", $searchArray);
    $string = preg_replace($pattern,$repl,$string);
    return $string;
}

function dashReplace($str) {
    return "<span class='txtOlg'>" . $str . "</span>";
}

function insertWordBoundaries($str){
    return "/\b". preg_quote($str,"/") ."\b/";
}

$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettings all industry.';
echo sanitize($text,$searchArray);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2gved)

My goal is to pack only the matching words in a separate JSON.
How can I do this, can you guide me?

Comment: Everything is possible (except the wooden stove). And SO is not guiding service. You have to try something on your own and if you face some problem show us your code and ask specific question.

Comment: You talk about JSON, but I don't see any above.  I see an array of individual words, and then one long string.  Where does JSON come into play here?

Comment: @Dilek (Merhaba) Yes, Actually, I want to get it in an array. In just one array - So I want to prevent it from being searched again from more than 50 thousand word pools.

Comment: Printing only matching words in a separate array. I don't think it has anything to do with AJAX. Thank you for your help & time @Dilek :)

Comment: (O kelimeler nereden geliyor ?) where that words come from?

Comment: All words are kept in the database. When a text is written, the raw-text content in the database is matched and the text is presented to the end user with matching words. This process takes 5-6 seconds because the word pool is huge. Therefore, we want to separate the matching words of raw text. [Kelimeler veritabanından geliyor, temiz metin yazıldığında mevcut olan veritabanındaki kelimeler ile eşleştiriliyor ve son kullanıcıya gösterimi sağlanıyor. Ne yazık ki bu süreç 5-6 saniye kadar sürüyor ve biz de metnin eşleşen kelimelerini ayırmak istiyoruz.] @Dilek

Comment: Emre6 and @Dilek  Please note that this is an English-language site.  Please refrain from using other languages.

Comment: @Emre6 use delboy's answer! change `$text = 'Lorem Ipsum';` to data coming from databse and this `$searchArray = array('settings all');` to words you want to filter, it will give you an array of matches words. **but** I dont think this will be a solution for your server web performance, even will take much longer then its now. you need to find a beter (faster) way of querying from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! after some researches I came up with this, to make a search faster using php and mysql.

**1. CREATE INDEX Example**

The SQL statement below creates an index named "idx_lastname" on the "LastName" column in the "Persons" table.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_lastname
ON Persons (LastName);
```

See here :[Slow PHP searching in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386527/slow-php-searching-in-database)

There are several methods creating indexes (combination of columns) etc. you probably know them.

**2.FULLTEXT**

I use fulltext in all my projects its working fine for me never had a problem for performance.
Mysql site:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

See here : http://www.bakale.com/mysql/myfultext.htm

**Other solutions**

check mysql setup and use faster methods and create your columns on that.
Example : char is faster than varchar but char is less word limited.

> You need to look into mysql faster methods.

Given answer is the best solution for the way you wanted to do, so I wont give a duplicate answer.

But I realy dont think that solution will make faster your server performance.
Even will make it more slower, you need to look into mysql setup and how to make it faster, how to send minimum queries etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_intersect($array1, $array2);` which gives you an array where both arrays have that value. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

```
<?php

$searchArray = array('settings all','print', 'sum', 'industry');
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettings all industry.';
$text = str_replace('.', '', $text); // and any other characters you dont want
$checkArray = explode(' ', $text);

var_dump(array_intersect($searchArray, $checkArray));
```

https://3v4l.org/17cWj

The only problem with this approach is that one of your words is actually TWO words, so matching `settings all` wouldn't work.